# How to get value from two livedata at the same time in android

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

`private var purchaseArrayList = ArrayList<PurchaseModelWithId>()`  //initialize 1 st arraylist

`private var saleArrayList = ArrayList<SaleModelWithId>()` //initialize 2 nd arraylist

```
purchaseViewModel.showPurchaseItems(requireContext()).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { purchaseList->
                    purchaseArrayList = purchaseList as ArrayList<PurchaseModelWithId>

                    saleViewModel.saleLiveData(requireContext()).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, saleList -> {
                        saleArrayList = saleList as ArrayList<SaleModelWithId>
                        
                        //here I want two arraylist value but above code not works for me
       })

 })
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more of your problem

Comment: Please share your `ViewModel` codes too

Comment: https://prnt.sc/18ibfg6

Comment: above is my purchase viewmodel

Comment: https://prnt.sc/18ibo0z

Comment: this is my sale viewmodel

Comment: I want to observe this above two livedata in my activity at the same time

Comment: I'd love to answer your question but Stack Overflow says that external links count as self-promotion, but technically you are looking for MediatorLiveData and livedata combine logic

Comment: Thank you so much. I post my question once again.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68256835/how-to-get-value-from-two-livedata-at-the-same-time

Comment: This is my new question. Now you can answer

Answer (score -1):

when you call showPurchaseItems(),return will be executed before set the Value to your live data.

So avoid return live data value, when you set value for live data within call back methods.

First make showPurchaseItems() method and saleLiveData() method as void method.

Then create  getter methods to get value of finalPurchaseList,saleList in viewmodel.

```
public MutableLiveData<yourReurnType> getFinalPurchaseList(){

return finalPurchaseList;
}

public MutableLiveData<yourReurnType> getSaleList(){

return saleList;
}
```

Then in your activity call your two methods to set value for your live data.
After that observe live data.

```
showPurchaseItems();
saleLiveData();

viewmodel.getFinalPurchaseList().(requireContext()).observe(viewLifecycleOwner){}

viewmodel.getSaleList().(requireContext()).observe(viewLifecycleOwner){


}
```

Please note :using two viewModels in one activity/fragment is not good practice.