# How to get value from two livedata at the same time

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

https://prnt.sc/18ibfg6     // This is my first live data it return arraylist of some object

https://prnt.sc/18ibo0z     // This is my second live data it return another arraylist of some object

purchaseViewModel.showPurchaseItems(requireContext()).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {purchaseList ->
purchaseArrayList = purchaseList as ArrayList
saleViewModel.saleLiveData(requireContext()).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {saleList ->
saleArrayList = saleList as ArrayList
getReportList(purchaseArrayList, saleArrayList) //I want two arraylist
})
})

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57237829/115145